# bind a table on click event of button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor. I have a list method in controller, so want to bind this list to table on click event of a button. How will I achieve this functionality.
Here is my controller method:

```
  public ActionResult getItnList(string scanCode)
        {
           List<List<String>> getitnDetails_List = getitnDetails(date, name);
           ViewBag.getitnDetails = getitnDetails_List;
           return Json(new { getitnDetails_List = getitnDetails_List }, JsonRequestBehavior. AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is my view code:

```
 @{
    List<List<String>> str = (List<List<String>>)ViewBag.getitnDetails;
  }
<table id="list" width="100%">
  <td><b>Harvest Date</b></td>
  <td><b>Product</b></td>
@for (int i = 0; i <= str.Count - 1; i++)
  <td>@str[i][0].ToString()</td>
  <td>@str[i][1].ToString()</td>
</table>
```

How will I bind this table to list on click event of button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. But if you want to get the list on the click of a button you can use jQuery .getJSON (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to retrieve the list data and then insert it with javascript. Or you could render the list in the action and simply use json .get and insert the result.

Comment: I already have data in Controller List. I just want to bind this list to table on button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**View**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                PhoneNo
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
        @{var list = ViewBag.RegisterItems; }
        @if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var m in list)
            {
            <tr>
            <td>
                        <input id="txtName-@m.ID.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value="@m.Name.ToString()"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                        <input id="txtPhoneNo-@m.ID.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value="@m.PhoneNo.ToString()"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                        <input id="txtAddress-@m.ID.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value="@m.Address.ToString()"/>
                    </td>

            </tr>

            }
        }
    </table>
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult CustomerInfo()
    {
        ViewBag.RegisterItems = GetAllRegisterData();
        return View();
    }
```